# push_back std::pair into std::vector error

Tags: c++, stl, malloc, assertion, memory-corruption

When I try to add a pair to a vector I get this error:

```
table: malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted
```

Here is the method:

```
std::vector<std::pair <int, int> > AI::genPosNormal(int p, int dice)
{
  std::vector<std::pair <int, int> > pos;
  std::pair<int, int> step;

  for(int i = p; i < 25-dice; i++){
    if(board[BLACK][i] > 0 && board[WHITE][i+dice] < 2){
      step.first = i;
      step.second = dice;
      pos.push_back(step);
    }
  }
  return pos;
}
```

Comment: Seems like the heap is corrupted. Probably not by the code you show - that looks ok.

Comment: The push_back looks OK. Have you checked that you are within the bounds of `board`?

Comment: Try running your code with valgrind, it could show you where the memory error occurs. Also have you done any debugging so far?

Comment: yes, board is a matrix board[2][26],

Comment: Try a debugger. Check at which value if i the error occurs... I would also add an assert to assure that
    p < 25-dice
holds

Comment: I found the solution, the problem was a call of a malloc, I replaced it with static allocation.Thank you

Comment: @yonutix: You haven't fixed the problem, just moved it. Whatever was corrupting the heap is now corrupting static data instead. The easiest way to fix the root cause would be to put the `malloc` back and use a memory checker like Valgrind to find exactly where the corruption is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little to late. But I found using .reserve() in std::vector of std::pair resolves the issue. I still have to figure out why the error is caused but seems like there in an stl_uninitialized.h which raises an error flag.

Comment: Starring to check back in two more years!